# Glassfish 3.1 printing lots of stange SEVEREs

Tags: glassfish-3

I'm seeing a strange error in my GF logs that recently cropped up. I'm just wondering if anyone knows what might be happening (i know it's a stab in the dark). I'm using GF 3.1. My app is ejb 3.1 (build 43) and JPA with JSF 2 (using icefaces) frontend. These exceptions are slowing down my app considerably but not affecting its functionality as far as i can see. this is what i see (over and over):

```
SEVERE: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionManager (type com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl)
SEVERE: jdbc (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: java:global (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: ejb (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: __SYSTEM (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: UserTransaction (type com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionNamingProxy$UserTransactionProxy)
SEVERE: temp (type org.glassfish.javaee.services.ResourceProxy)
SEVERE: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionManager (type com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl)
SEVERE: jdbc (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: java:global (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: ejb (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: __SYSTEM (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: UserTransaction (type com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionNamingProxy$UserTransactionProxy)
SEVERE: temp (type org.glassfish.javaee.services.ResourceProxy)
SEVERE: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionManager (type com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl)
SEVERE: jdbc (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: java:global (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: ejb (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: __SYSTEM (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: UserTransaction (type com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionNamingProxy$UserTransactionProxy)
SEVERE: temp (type org.glassfish.javaee.services.ResourceProxy)
SEVERE: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionManager (type com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl)
SEVERE: jdbc (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: java:global (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: ejb (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
SEVERE: __SYSTEM (type com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try looking for some System.err in the JNDIUtils class ;)